# NSMutableArray integer storage

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsmutablearray, long-integer

I am trying to store numbers inside the NSMutableArray, and have wrapped them like so:

```
-(IBAction)opUp:(id)sender{
    opBool = YES;
    opNum = [sender tag];
    [numArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithLong:number2]];
    [opArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:opNum]];
    number1 = 0;
    number2 = 0;
    opNum = 0;
    NSLog(@"Operand %i", opNum);
    NSLog(@"%i, %i", numArray.count, opArray.count);
 }
```

But when I call them later using this:

```
    final2 = [numArray objectAtIndex:i];
    operthing = [opArray objectAtIndex:i];
```

I get this error message:

> operthing equals 111526320

'operthing' is not supposed to go beyond 20.
Can someone help me with this?
Thanks.

Comment: How are you getting `operthing`'s value? Are you using the `value` method corresponding with the `numberWith` method you called?

Comment: Please show the code you're using to create `opNum` and to inspect `operthing`.

Comment: operthing = [[opArray objectAtIndex:i] intValue]

Comment: @JesseGumpo : post it as an answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
operthing = [[opArray objectAtIndex:i] intValue];
```